# print 3 columns from pandas data set in a table

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have this data:

```
project:  group:  sum:
A         John    12
A         Sam     10
B         Sun     4
B         Toy     5
B         Joy     7
C         Sam     11
```

The data is in data set frame_main.
I wanted to sum up by project so I did:

```
result_main = pd.concat(frame_main).groupby(["project","group"]).sum()
```

It basically doing what I wanted, which is summing up the third column and group by the first:

```
project:  group:  sum:
A         John    12
          Sam     10
B         Sun     4
          Toy     5
          Joy     7
C         Sam     11
```

But now when I'm trying to print it using the following:

```
print(tabulate(result_main, headers="keys", tablefmt='psql'))
```

It prints like that:

```
+---------------------------+-----------------+                                                                                       
|                           |   sum:          |                                                                                       
|---------------------------+-----------------|                                                                                       
| ('A', 'John')             |             12  |                                                                                       
| ('A', 'Sam')              |             10  |                                                                                       
| ('B', 'Sun')              |             4   |
| ('B', 'Toy')              |             5   |                                                                                       
| ('B', 'Joy')              |             7   |                                                                                       
| ('C', 'Sam')              |             11  |
```

How can I print so it would look like the output above?
I need 3 columns and grouped by the first.

Comment: to_excel will preserve the format, but don't know what you neeed the printout for so  not sure if this helps you

Comment: FYI.. pandas 1.0.0 did add the `to_markdown` method, so you can do this print(result_main.to_markdown(tablefmt='psql'))`

Answer (score 4):

Much like @Craig we can mask those duplicate value in 'project:' column.

```
df_sum = df_sum.reset_index()
df_sum['project:'] = df_sum['project:'].mask(df_sum['project:'].duplicated(),'')

print(df_sum.set_index('project:').to_markdown(tablefmt='psql'))
```

Output:

```
+------------+----------+--------+
| project:   | group:   |   sum: |
|------------+----------+--------|
| A          | John     |     12 |
|            | Sam      |     10 |
| B          | Sun      |      4 |
|            | Toy      |      5 |
|            | Joy      |      7 |
| C          | Sam      |     11 |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I needed

Comment: @Jenny You're welcome, would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution if it helped  you.

Answer (score 2):

The dataframe created after the `.sum()` operation has a multi-index. If you reset the index you will get a table that looks the way you want. The `.reset_index()` method allows you to specify which index you want to drop (and keeps the others). In your case, you want to keep the first index but not the second, so use `.reset_index(level=[1])` as shown here:

```py
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

result_main = pd.concat(frame_main).groupby(["project","group"]).sum()
result_main = result_main.reset_index(level=[1])
print(tabulate(result_main, headers="keys", tablefmt='psql'))
```

Will produce:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| project   | group   |   sum |
|-----------+---------+-------|
| A         | John    |    12 |
| A         | Sam     |    10 |
| B         | Joy     |     7 |
| B         | Sun     |     4 |
| B         | Toy     |     5 |
| C         | Sam     |    11 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

As Scott Boston mentions in a comment, since Pandas 1.0.0, you can use the `.to_markdown()` method instead of `tabulate` to achieve the same thing, but you still have to reset the index to get three columns.

This is equivalent to the last line of the code above:

```py
print(result_main.to_markdown(tablefmt='psql'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks silly but does exactly what you need:

```
result_main.index = [a for a in result_main.index]
```

Output:

```
           sum
(A, John)   12
(A, Sam)    10
(B, Joy)     7
(B, Sun)     4
(B, Toy)     5
(C, Sam)    11
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df.index=df.index.values
df
Out[350]: 
           sum
(A, John)   12
(A, Sam)    10
(B, Sun)     4
(B, Toy)     5
(B, Joy)     7
(C, Sam)    11
```